# emacs: seq-1.11 not found while booting with prelude

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I'm new to emacs, and I'm getting started with prelude configuration. While invoking emacs, I've got a message: `error "Package 'seq-1.11' is unavailable"`. It might be the dependency of `beacon` package according to the `--debug-init` log. Although it seems `seq` package is inside https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/ depository, I couldn't find the package in `package-install`. I've even tried to install the `seq` package manually to `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`, but the same error message--`seq is unavailable` was still there. Any ideas to solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of Emacs do you have? (Check with `M-x version RET`.)

Comment: `GNU emacs 24.3.50.1`